# Question about adding a frailty term in survival() R

Tags: survival, frailty

If I add a frailty term in the coxph() function using the survival package in R, we model unobserved heterogeneity of clustered data.

Does this only model unobserved heterogeneity of overlapping data? Or also non-overlapping? What I mean by this: Do we also model the unobserved heterogeneity for the whole study time of, for example, twins who entered and left at different times in the study.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I am understanding your question, but if the twins belong to the same cluster you are defining, than yes, it should not matter if the study entrances of exits are at different times.

In fact, frailty models can be used for recurrent event data within a person(which would be a cluster), which often involve entering and exiting at difference times. For example, readmission to a hospital. After the first readmission, the entry(discharge) and exit(readmission) for a second readmission for the same person would necessarily need to occur during a different entry and exit time than the first readmission.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is what I meant with my question.